# How to create a new column based on row values in python?

Tags: pandas

I have data like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df["collection_amount"] = 100, 200, 300
df["25%_coll"] = 1, 0, 1
df["75%_coll"] = 0, 1, 1
df["month"] = 4, 5, 6
```

I want to create a output like below:
[image]

basically if 25% is 1 then it should create a column based on month as a new column.

Please help me thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: list_ib = ['25%_coll']
   list_ib_1 = ['month']

for i in list_ib:
    for j in list_ib_1:
        if i == 0:
            break
        else:
            bina = df[i]
            df['bina_' + str(i) + '_' + j] = bina

Answer (score 0):

This should work: do ask if something doesn't make sense

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['25%_coll'][i]==1:
        df['month_%i_25%%_coll'%df.month[i]]=[df.collection_amount[i] if k==i else 0 for k in range(len(df))]
    if df['75%_coll'][i]==1:
        df['month_%i_75%%_coll'%df.month[i]]=[df.collection_amount[i] if k==i else 0 for k in range(len(df))]
```

Answer (score 0):

To build the new columns you could try the following:

```
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=["month", "collection_amount"])
df2.loc[df2["value"].eq(0), "collection_amount"] = 0
df2["new_cols"] = "month_" + df2["month"].astype("str") + "_" + df2["variable"]
df2 = df2.pivot_table(
    index="month", columns="new_cols", values="collection_amount",
    fill_value=0, aggfunc="sum"
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

- `.melt()` the dataframe with index columns `month` and `collection_amount`.
- Set the appropriate `collection_amount` values to 0.
- Build the new column names in column `new_cols`.

  ```
       month  collection_amount  variable  value          new_cols
    0      4                100  25%_coll      1  month_4_25%_coll
    1      5                  0  25%_coll      0  month_5_25%_coll
    2      6                300  25%_coll      1  month_6_25%_coll
    3      4                  0  75%_coll      0  month_4_75%_coll
    4      5                200  75%_coll      1  month_5_75%_coll
    5      6                300  75%_coll      1  month_6_75%_coll
  ```
- Use `.pivot_table()` on this dataframe to build the new columns.

The rest isn't completely clear: Either use `df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)`, or `df.merge(df2, ...)` to merge on `month` (with `.reset_index()` without `drop=True`).

Result for the sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "collection_amount": [100, 200, 300],
    "25%_coll": [1, 0, 1], "75%_coll": [0, 1, 1],
    "month": [4, 5, 6]
})
```

is

```
new_cols  month_4_25%_coll  month_4_75%_coll  month_5_25%_coll  \
0                      100                 0                 0   
1                        0                 0                 0   
2                        0                 0                 0   

new_cols  month_5_75%_coll  month_6_25%_coll  month_6_75%_coll  
0                        0                 0                 0  
1                      200                 0                 0  
2                        0               300               300
```